# Date Labeller year format with custom string in cruise control .net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am using dateLabeller  in Cruise control .net for labeling purpose.

```
 <labeller type="dateLabeller">

</labeller>
```

it is working fine for me, each time build label is incrementing every time. 
But i also want to add some text before date so i have use following code

```
<labeller type="dateLabeller">
  <yearFormat>QAT-0000</yearFormat>
  <revisionFormat>0000</revisionFormat>
</labeller>
```

Now each time a fore build is trigger same label is generating.

How can i fix this problem

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the format values just as you would use them in `Int32.ToString(String)`. Find information on Custom Numeric Format Strings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

So this should fix it:

```
<labeller type="dateLabeller">
  <yearFormat>'QAT-'0000</yearFormat>
</labeller>
```

**Update:** I took a look at the sources and found out that `dateLabeller` isn't capable of processing non-numeric labels since the label of the last successful integration is parsed into a `System.Version` object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is generating same build number each time i.e. QAT-date.001 and QAT-date.001 for same day.

Comment: i have tried it by defaultlabeller that has prifix and postfix both tags. SO can u tell me how can i declare a variable in ccnet.config that has current date so i can refrence this variable inside my defaultlabeller block as a prefix.

Comment: You could use the integration property `$\[$CCNetBuildDate\]`